# If the user is logged in, redirect to the homepage instead of redirecting to the login page using React Router

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-router, react-router-dom

"If the user is already authenticated, I aim to restrict their access to the login page. Currently, when attempting to navigate to '/login' while already logged in, the system still redirects to '/login'. However, my intention is to prevent this redirection and maintain the user at their current authenticated state

route.jsx

```
import { createBrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Main from "../Layout/Main";
import Home from "../Components/Home/Home/Home";
import Login from "../Components/Login/Login";
import SignUp from "../Components/SignUp/SignUp";
import Checkout from "../Components/Checkout/Checkout";
import Bookings from "../Components/Bookings/Bookings";
import PrivateRoute from "./PrivateRoute";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Main></Main>,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/",
        element: <Home></Home>,
      },
      {
        path: "/login",
        element: <Login></Login>,
      },
      {
        path: "/signup",
        element: <SignUp></SignUp>,
      },
      {
        path: "/bookings",
        element: (
          <PrivateRoute>
            <Bookings></Bookings>
          </PrivateRoute>
        ),
      },
      {
        path: "/services/:id",
       
        element:  <PrivateRoute><Checkout></Checkout></PrivateRoute>,
        loader: ({ params }) =>
          fetch(`http://localhost:5000/services/${params.id}`),
      },
    ],
  },
]);

export default router;
```

privateroute.jsx:

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import { AuthContext } from "../providers/AuthProvider";
import { Navigate, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const PrivateRoute = ({ children }) => {
  const { user, loading } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const location = useLocation();
  if (loading) {
    return <progress className="progress w-full "></progress>;
  }
  if (user?.email) {
    return children;
  }
  return <Navigate to="/login" state={{from:location}} replace></Navigate>;
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

I tried this, but I can still access the '/login' page even when I'm logged in.

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import { AuthContext } from "../providers/AuthProvider";
import { Navigate, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const PrivateRoute = ({ children }) => {
  const { user, loading } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const location = useLocation();
  if (loading) {
    return <progress className="progress w-full "></progress>;
  }
  if (user?.email) {
    return children;
  }
  if (user?.email && location.pathname === "/login") {
    
    return <Navigate to="/" replace />;
  }

  return <Navigate to="/login" state={{ from: location }} replace></Navigate>;
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your logic in `PrivateRoute`. Change your `PrivateRoute` logic to check when the user is logged in and is going to `/login` route.

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ children }) => {
    const { user, loading } = useContext(AuthContext);
    const location = useLocation();

    if (loading) {
        return <progress className="progress w-full "></progress>;
    }

    if (user?.email) {
        // If the user is authenticated, check if login route is called
        if (location.pathname === "/login") {
            return <Navigate to="/" replace />;
        }
        return children;
    }

    return <Navigate to="/login" state={{ from: location }} replace></Navigate>;
};
```

Comment: Still facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

A pattern I used to follow was to have `PublicRoute` component for public routes, like a landing page, or login/sign-up page in this case. You could basically do the opposite logic of `PrivateRoute` in `PublicRoute`. This way it's more maintainable and reusable than piling on different conditionals for public routes inside `PrivateRoute` component. Logic should be pretty simple. Something like below...

```
const PublicRoute = ({ children }) => {
    const { user, loading } = useContext(AuthContext);

    if (loading) {
        return <progress className="progress w-full "></progress>;
    }

    if (user?.email) {
        return <Navigate to="/" replace />;
    }

    return children;
};
```